# How to implement pagination in graphql which returns pagination metadata along with dataset

Tags: node.js, pagination, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

Currently i use graphql default pagination, that is by using limit offset (code given below) . which is working fine. but instead of the team list  how can we include pagination metadata. and return the pagination metadata along with this. I use sequalize to fetch the data

```
            type Query {
            allTeams(page:Int, pageSize:Int): [Team]
        }
        type Team {
            id: Int
            name: String  
        }

        //resolver with pagination   

        const paginate = ( page, pageSize ) => { 
          var offset = page * pageSize;
          var limit =  pageSize;  
          return {
            offset,
            limit,
          };
        };

        export const resolvers = {
            Query: {     
                  allTeams: async (obj, args, context, info ) =>  Teams.findAll(           
                  paginate( args.page, args.pageSize ),         
                ),
            },
        }
```

The above code will only return the list of teams .
Is there any way i can return a the output as which contains team list and pagination details

```
         {
          "data": {
            "allTeams": [
              {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Team created from postman",

              },
              {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Team created from postman",

              }
              ]
            },
               "pageInfo": {
                "currentPage": 2,
                "perPage": 2,
                "itemCount": 4,
                "pageCount": 2,
                "hasPreviousPage": true,
                "hasNextPage": false
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you'll just need to add the pagination metadata to your schema and provide the data in your resolvers. So for the output you're looking to achieve, the schema would look like:

```
type Query {
  teams(page:Int, pageSize:Int): TeamsConnection
}

type TeamsConnection {
  results: [Team]
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}

type Team {
  id: Int
  name: String  
}

type PageInfo {
  currentPage: Int
  perPage: Int
  itemCount: Int
  pageCount: Int
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean
  hasNextPage: Boolean
}
```

Your resolver would then need to return the new shape of the response data. So something like:

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {     
    allTeams: async (obj, args, context, info ) => {
      const results = await Teams.findAll(           
        paginate(args.page, args.pageSize),         
      );
      return {
        results,
        pageInfo: {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```